# Weird Error after trying to display ViewController

Tags: ios, ios5, uitabbarcontroller

I have a ViewController, which is loaded into a tabbar.

At the moment when the whole thing gets displayed, the program receives `SIGABRT`and leaves me with this error:

`2012-03-01 21:53:21.118 GameControl[78897:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FavoriteViewController 0x68c8620> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key singleton.`

Anyone an idea what that could mean?

Heres the code where I setup my views:

```
RootViewController *rootController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
FavoriteViewController *favoriteController = [[FavoriteViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoriteViewController" bundle:nil];

rootController.xmlData = self.xmlData;
favoriteController.xmlData = self.xmlData;

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootController];

tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

navigationController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Root" image:nil tag:0];
favoriteController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Favorites" image:nil tag:0];

tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navigationController, favoriteController, nil];    

if ([[self.window subviews] count] != 0) {
    [[[self.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
```

And well, I'm using IOS5, with ARC but no Storyboards.

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have not added favoriteController to the tab bar controller or anywhere else. Is that intentional?

Comment: Well, I changed this for testing reasons...
Gonna edit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youre trying to acess the property singleton on you favoriteviewcontroller. perhaps there is an old link in your nib file?

Comment: Thanks, that was right ;)

Found that evil NIB File.